# Modifing keys of a dict while iterating

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

So I'm trying to modify keys of a dict while iterating through them, and it seems like this is something python does not really want you to do. Thus, I want to ask, how can I get around python's limit? This is my first code, and the problem is that dict.items() does not allow you to modify key's of dict, but rather gives you a view into the dict.

```
d = {k: dict(zip(v['EST'], v['value'])) for k, v in df1.groupby('variable')}

order = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
Days = [key for key in d]
Days.sort(key=order.index)

templist = []

Better version
for day in Days:
     for key, value in d[day].items():
        if 'EST' not in key :
            key = ''.join(('Time ', key))
            if 'Time' in key:               templist = key.rsplit(":", 1)
                 key = ''.join(templist)
                 print(f"Yes this is the {day}, {key} EST and the {value}")
```

Since this did not modify the original values of the dict, I tried to modify them while iterating but also got a RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

```
    for j in d[i]:
        if 'EST' not in j :
            d[j] = ''.join(('Time ', j))
```

Basically, I want to modify the keys of dict but I'm not being allowed, so what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Changing a key in a `dict` is equivalent to deleting the existing entry and adding a new one with the same value. Depending on what you want to do, that can be fiddly. Instead of changing the keys of the existing `dict`, loop through `.items()` and build a new one.

Comment: @BoarGules the problem is since I modify the key, looping through .items() again after modifying the key would just give me the old values. Except I'm somehow able to build a new dict while modifying the values.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the .items() call with a tuple.

Something like,

```py
for day in Days:
     for key, value in tuple(d[day].items()):
        if 'EST' not in key :
            key = ''.join(('Time ', key))
            if 'Time' in key:               templist = key.rsplit(":", 1)
                 key = ''.join(templist)
                 print(f"Yes this is the {day}, {key} EST and the {value}")
```

Update #1:
Okay, what I meant was,

```py
abc = dict()

for key, value in tuple(abc.items()):
    # Modify dict somehow
    abc[somekey] = somevalue # This would work
```

I'm unable to completely understand your requirement. But I do understand your problem and I think this would fix it.

Comment: I fail to see how that would allow me to change the keys even when I exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer for this is python does not allow you to modify the dictionary you're iterating over, thus, one needs to create a copy of the dict and iterate over the copy while using the copy's index to change the original dict. Just remember that there are two types of copying, deep and shallow. Use the right one for your needs.

```
    for key in dictionary_from_numpy[day].copy():
        if 'EST' not in key:
            copy_of_dictionary_from_numpy[day][x] = copy_of_dictionary_from_numpy[day].pop(key)
```

The second thing is you must pop the keys you want to remove from the dict. This would push your keys to the back of the dict, so be careful about this. This example is a bit clearer since actual values are in it.

`new['Friday']['rr1'] = d['Friday'].pop('1:00: AM')`